# Spring 3.1 @Cacheable - method still executed

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I'm trying to implement Spring 3.1 caching as explained [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/spring-31-cache-abstraction-tutorial.html) and [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/23/spring-3-1-m1-caching/), but it doesn't seem to be working: my method is run through every time even though it is marked @cacheable. What am I doing wrong?

I've moved it into a junit test case with its own configuration file to isolate it from the rest of my application, but the problem still happens. Here are the relevant files:

Spring-test-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
<cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
      p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
</beans>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache>
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<cache name="cache"
       maxElementsInMemory="100"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="120"
       timeToLiveSeconds="120"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
       diskPersistent="false"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

</ehcache>
```

MyTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:spring-test-servlet.xml"})
@Component
public class MyTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testCache1(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println("Calling someMethod...");
            System.out.println(someMethod(0));
        }
    }

    @Cacheable("testmethod")
    private int someMethod(int val){
        System.out.println("Not from cache");
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Relevant Pom entries: (spring-version = 3.1.1.RELEASE)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

when I run the test, Spring puts out some debug messages that looks like my cache is initialized without errors

```
DEBUG: config.ConfigurationHelper - No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
DEBUG: ehcache.Cache - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
DEBUG: ehcache.Cache - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
DEBUG: config.ConfigurationHelper - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
DEBUG: store.MemoryStore - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore for cache
DEBUG: disk.DiskStorageFactory - Failed to delete file cache.data
DEBUG: disk.DiskStorageFactory - Failed to delete file cache.index
DEBUG: disk.DiskStorageFactory - Matching data file missing (or empty) for index file. Deleting index file /var/folders/qg/xwdvsg6x3mx_z_rcfvq7lc0m0000gn/T/cache.index
DEBUG: disk.DiskStorageFactory - Failed to delete file cache.index
DEBUG: ehcache.Cache - Initialised cache: cache
DEBUG: config.ConfigurationHelper - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured. Skipping for 'cache'.
DEBUG: config.ConfigurationHelper - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'cache'.
```

but the debug output shows no cache checks between method calls to someMethod and the print statement from inside someMethod prints every time.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, **a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object**, **will not lead to an actual
>   caching** at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Cacheable - considering using the aspectj mode in this case.

and

> Method visibility and `@Cacheable`/`@CachePut`/`@CacheEvict`
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the `@Cache` annotations only to
>   methods with **public visibility**.

1. You self-invoke `someMethod` in the same target object.
2. Your `@Cacheable` method is not public.

Comment: In addition to this, you'll need to extract to an Interface so Spring can dynamically write a wrapper to your class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a cache that matches the name you are referencing in you annotation ("testmethod"). Create an entry in your ehcache.xml for that cache as well.

Comment: This was also an issue with my original code, which became apparent once I called the method in a way that tried to put it in the cache (see accepted solution)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lee Chee Kiam: Here is my solution for small projects with only marginal usage of bypassing (not annotated) method calls. **The DAO is simply injected into itself as a proxy and calls it's own methods using that proxy instead of a simple method call.** So @Cacheable is considered without doing complicated insturmentation.

In-code documentation is strongly advidsed, as it may look strange to colleagues. But its easy to test, simple, quick to achieve and spares me the full blown AspectJ instrumentation. However, for more heavy usage I'd also advice the AspectJ solution as Lee Chee Kiam did.

```
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class PersonDao {

    private final PersonDao _personDao;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDao(PersonDao personDao) {
        _personDao = personDao;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "defaultCache", key = "#id")
    public Person findPerson(int id) {
        return getSession().getPerson(id);
    }

    public List<Person> findPersons(int[] ids) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (int id : ids) {
            list.add(_personDao.findPerson(id));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it just the @Scope annotation thats bypassing the proxy mode?  I have a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486620/correct-key-annotation-for-caching-on-items-in-a-list-rather-then-the-whole-list

Comment: I'm sorry, i think I didn't get the question right. I dont see the connection to your post.

Comment: "bypassing" in that context means, that the method is not annotated with @Cachable BUT it uses the chached methods of the injected proxy internally, WHICH in turn is a proxy of "this" itslef. Kinda freaky ;) The object is injected into itself as a proxy to avoid complicated instumentation.

Comment: Its an interesting hack but I'm confused about how such an object gets constructed.

Comment: Constructed via the magic of ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS.  Spring makes a proxy that isn't resolved until its used.  When this class accesses the proxy the proxy gets resolved into a reference to the underlying object. But Spring can also wrap the proxy with caching wrappers to make it cacheable.